# Fragments app creates two icons - one for main activity and one for on of the fragment activities

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

So yes, my fragments app that uses two fragments creates two icons when installed on the device - one for main activity and one for one of the fragment activities. Both of them are working fine.

How do I make so that my app is represented by only one launcher icon??

Yes i know that is really dull question.

Thanks in advance xx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit your Manifest file to have only one activity with intent-filter like this one below:

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Thanks a bundle, that is it. I will accept your answer asap xx